# Sharing Internet over Wireless Router

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-router

I have a very strange question today - how do I share my dial up internet (yeah I know you are gonna say that is slow but broadband internet isn't available in my area), so dial up and 3G connection is all I got. I also have a Vodafone USB 3G modem that picks up 3G network, I am planning to use my Vodafone 3G modem in the day since I have free dial up internet from 7:00 pm in the night untill 7am the next morning.

Some additional details: 
* My PC is running Windows XP Professional SP3
* I have a Sitecom Wireless Router 150N X1 WLR-      1000

I would appreciate it if anyone can provide me with a step-by-step guide!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's like setting up Internet Connection Sharing in Windows.

Step 1: Go to the address of the gateway 192.168.1.1 in browser
Step 2: From [home-network-help.com](http://www.home-network-help.com/wireless-router.html):

> Setting WAN (Wide Area Network) Setting
>
> Static IP - Choose this option to set static IP information provided
>   to you by your ISP. You will required to type in all network
>   information manually if select this option. This option is mostly used
>   by business users. Lot of works if use this option, try to avoid this
>   if possible.
>
> PPPoE - Choose this option if your ISP uses PPPoE. Your ISP will
>   provide you with a username and password. This option is typically
>   used for most DSL services.
>
> PPTP - Same as PPPoE, This option is mostly used by DSL service users
>   with provided username, password and IP information.
>
> L2TP - This option is mostly used by DSL service users is Europe with
>   provided username, password and L2TP dedicated server information.
>
> Telstra Cable: This option is mostly used by DSL service users with
>   provided username, password and Heart Beat dedicated server
>   information.
>
> As a cable modem user, I will choose Automatic Configuration – DHCP
>   option. I won't clone MAC address because the service registration is
>   tied to cable modem's MAC address.
>
> At the same setup page, set up the IP address for the router. This
>   will be the router/gateway IP address that you will set on your
>   network computers. The LAN IP address is private in your home network
>   and cannot be seen from the internet. I set my router with IP
>   192.168.1.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Do not just copy and paste contents of other websites here. Include a proper citation by quoting the passages and adding a link to the source. Thank you.